# Feeds module import csv: problem with mapping

Tags: 8, feeds

I've been trying to import data from a .csv file into my content type but 
have found some trouble mapping the headers of the csv file to fields.

How do you map a field to a header (since I'm not seeing that
as an option in Feed)? I've tried using the `new Source option` and putting the name of the header but had some errors importing.

[image]

I'm planning to use the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module and stay away from code since a
site admin will be importing subsequent files and is not very familiar with drush.

I used to use the [Feeds Import Preview](https://www.drupal.org/project/feedspreview) module on D7 but have not been
able to find something similar for D8.

Comment: It's difficult to say without your importer configuration. Are you using the upload file method? Which parser did you choose? You can name your CSV column titles as your target machine names, this should make them match automatically.

Comment: The source value has to exactly match the column name in your CSV file. Unlike the D7 version, CSV sources are case sensitive. Porting Feeds Import Preview to D8 is on my wishlist. I have a less user friendly version of it in my Feeds DEV sandbox: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/megachriz/2950698. That version also doesn't work well together with the Download fetcher. So for these two reasons I have not added it to the main module yet.